# Doctrine Class inheritence id on child entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, inheritance, doctrine-orm, entity

Hi, 
In Doctrine 2.6.1: [6.3. Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)
I use sql server 2014, Symfony 3.3, PHP 7.1.9

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="[Persons]")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"visitor" = "Visitor", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
abstract class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="[IdPerson]", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
    // ...
}

/** 
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="[Employes]")
 */
class Employee extends Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="[IdPerson]", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="???")
     */
    private $id;
    // ...
}

/** 
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="[Visitors]")
 */
class Visitor extends Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="[IdPerson]", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="???")
     */
    private $id;
    // ...
}
```

**In my DataBase**

- The primary key of my [Visitors] table is a foreign key of the
  primary key of the [Persons] table.
- The primary key of my [Employees] table is a foreign key of the
  primary key of the [Persons] table.

My question is : How to configure doctrine to manage strategy of child identity relative to the parent ?

Comment: I finally found the solution: You have to put the strategy on NONE